# Java File cannot be deleted nor renamed

Tags: java, file, file-rename, delete-file

See my code below:
I can write a key and a string in one line of a file. If the key already exists I want to overwrite it by creating a new file and fill it with the content of my source file. In the end I am going to delete the old file and rename my temporary file. But it does not work. As you can see I print booleans for deleting and renameTo methods. Both are returned as "false".

I read in some other Threads that I have to close all Readers and Writers that are in contact with my file in order to be able to rename or delete it.

You see my fault?

(Note that some comments are written in german)

```
public static boolean dini_Set(String filepath, String key, String value) throws IOException
{
    if(key.length() <= 0 || value.length() <= 0) return false;

    String pfilepath = rootdirectory.concat(filepath);
    File pfile = new File(pfilepath);
    //dini_Remove(filepath.concat(".part"));

    if(dini_Exists(filepath) == false) return false;

    // Checkt ob der Key schon existiert

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(pfilepath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String ausw;
    boolean foundkeybool = false;
    while((ausw = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
       String foundkey = ausw.substring(0,ausw.indexOf("="));
       //System.out.println(foundkey);
       if(foundkey.equals(key))
       {
           foundkeybool = true;
           System.out.println(foundkeybool);

           // Key exists and content has to be overwritten

           String newline = key.concat("=").concat(value);

           String tmpdir = rootdirectory.concat("tmp.tmp");
           File tmp = new File(tmpdir);
           tmp.createNewFile();
           String currentLine;
           FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tmpdir);
           BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

           br.close();
           fr.close();

           fr = new FileReader(pfilepath);
           br = new BufferedReader(fr);

           while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
           {
                // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                System.out.println(trimmedLine);
                if(trimmedLine.equals(ausw)) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Austauschen: "+newline);
                    bw.write(newline);
                }
                else
                {
                    bw.write(currentLine);
                    System.out.println("Lassen: "+currentLine);
                }
                bw.newLine();
           }

           br.close();
           fr.close();
           bw.close();
           fw.close();
           tmp.setWritable(true);
           pfile.setWritable(true);
           // boolean removed = dini_Remove(filepath);
           boolean removed = pfile.delete();
           System.out.println("Datei wurde gelöscht: "+removed);
           boolean renamed = tmp.renameTo(pfile);
           System.out.println("Datei umbenannt: "+renamed);
           break;
       }
    }

    // if key does now exists we can create a new one
    if(foundkeybool == false)
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(pfilepath,true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(key.concat("=").concat(value));
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not fix your problem, but it will get you closer.

You MUST ensure that any resource that you open is closed properly.  Currently in your code, if, for some reason, an exception is thrown, none of your resources will be closed.

Even if you're not interested in dealing with the exception within the method, you should still wrap the file access code within a `try-finally` block

```
FileReader fr = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    fr = new FileReader(pfilepath);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);    
    //...//
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
    try {
        fr.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

You may find that you only need to close the `BufferedReader` and it should be calling `close` on it's child `Reader`, but I'm paranoid about ensuring that everything is clean

If you are using Java 7, you may wish to take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

**Updated**

I'm not sure your code makes sense.  Basically, what you should be doing, is reading the entire source file and writing it the temp location (as you don't know in advance if the key needs to be updated, and you would probably need to read the source file anyway to find out).

Once this has being completed, if you made changes to the temp file, delete the source file and rename the temp file into it's place.

You code seems mighty inefficient to me...

Answer (score 0):

Okai, I want to give you a brief update about the code.

I changed it this way and for now it is working as it should.

Do you have some more things I can change to optimize the code?

```
public static boolean dini_Set(String filepath, String key, String value) throws IOException
{
    if(key.length() <= 0 || value.length() <= 0) return false;

    String pfilepath = rootdirectory.concat(filepath);
    File pfile = new File(pfilepath);
    //dini_Remove(filepath.concat(".part"));

    if(dini_Exists(filepath) == false) return false;

    // Checkt ob der Key schon existiert

    boolean foundkeybool = false;
    File tmp = null;

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pfilepath)))
    {           
        String ausw;

        while((ausw = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
           String foundkey = ausw.substring(0,ausw.indexOf("="));
           System.out.println(foundkey);
           if(foundkey.equals(key))
           {
               foundkeybool = true;
               System.out.println(foundkeybool);

               //Key exists and content has to be overwritten

               String newline = key.concat("=").concat(value);

               String tmpdir = rootdirectory.concat("tmp.tmp");
               tmp = new File(tmpdir);
               tmp.createNewFile();
               String currentLine;

               try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpdir)))
               {
                   try(BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pfilepath)))                
                   {
                       while((currentLine = br2.readLine()) != null) 
                       {
                            //trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                            System.out.println(trimmedLine);
                            if(trimmedLine.equals(ausw)) 
                            {
                                System.out.println("Austauschen: "+newline);
                                bw.write(newline);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bw.write(currentLine);
                                System.out.println("Lassen: "+currentLine);
                            }
                            bw.newLine();
                       }
                   }
               }    



               break;
           }
        }
    }

    if(foundkeybool == true)
    {
        tmp.setWritable(true);
       pfile.setWritable(true);
       //boolean removed = dini_Remove(filepath);
       boolean removed = pfile.delete();
       System.out.println("Datei wurde gelöscht: "+removed);
       boolean renamed = tmp.renameTo(pfile);
       System.out.println("Datei umbenannt: "+renamed);
    }
    else //(foundkeybool == false) if key does now exists we can create a new one
    {
        try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pfilepath,true)))
        {
            bw.write(key.concat("=").concat(value));
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
        }     
    }   
    return true;
}
```